# Is there a way to reset all the ID's of records in a h2 Database?

Tags: java, database, h2

I have an application that uses a h2 Database to store records of data. Each record is assigned a unique ID that I have used the auto-increment feature in h2 to do so. I want the lowest number to always be 1, or at least fill up the numbers that are not filled when a record has been deleted. What I mean is if there are 5 records numbered 1-5 and I delete the third record, I want the next record added to be numbered 3 instead of 6. How should I go about achieving this?

So far, I've tried

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ALTER COLUMN <id_column> RESTART WITH 1
```

Which doesn't have the intended effect that I wanted.

Edit: I'm an idiot, I wrote the SQL Query without actually executing it. The  does indeed restart from 1, but throws an exception whenever the increment value is in a value that already exists. How should I fix this?